# Passing HTML element containing variable to replace function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to replace a 'SearchString' with `<span style="background-color: yellow">SearchString</span>` in a targetString.

my SearchString is variable here so how can I achieve this.

What I tried is -

```
var applyHighlighting = function (highlightableElements, productFilterKeyword) {
for(var i =0; i< highlightableElements.length; i++){
    var regexp = new RegExp(productFilterKeyword, 'ig');
    var replaceKeyWord = highlightableElements[i].innerHTML.match(regexp);
    highlightableElements[i].innerHTML = highlightableElements[i].innerHTML.replace(regexp, '<span style="background-color: yellow">replaceKeyWord</span>');
}
```

Comment: My requirement is to highlight all the occurrences of (case insensitive) 'productFilterKeyword' from 'highlightableElements'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$&` to refer to your replacement regex:

```
highlightableElements[i].innerHTML = highlightableElements[i].innerHTML.replace(regexp, '<span style="background-color: yellow">$&</span>');
```

See more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

---

Here's a live example that also saves the original string (something you might've forgotten):

```js
var highlightableElements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < highlightableElements.length; i++) {
  highlightableElements[i].origHTML = highlightableElements[i].innerHTML
}
var applyHighlighting = function(productFilterKeyword) {
  for (var i = 0; i < highlightableElements.length; i++) {
    highlightableElements[i].innerHTML = highlightableElements[i].origHTML;
    var regexp = new RegExp(productFilterKeyword, 'ig');
    highlightableElements[i].innerHTML = highlightableElements[i].innerHTML.replace(regexp, '<span style="background-color: yellow">$&</span>');
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="applyHighlighting(this.value)">
<div>Some text here</div>
<div>And another HERE</div>
```

Comment: I think - `var replaceKeyWord = highlightableElements[i].innerHTML.match(regexp);` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your replacement string - you have a variable inside it, so it's not actually getting the value of the variable, just writing the variable name like a literal string. Do this instead:

```
...
    highlightableElements[i].innerHTML = highlightableElements[i].innerHTML.replace(regexp, '<span style="background-color: yellow">' + replaceKeyWord + '</span>');
}
```

That should hopefully solve any issues you're having.

Strictly speaking you can actually reduce the complexity significantly and just do this:

```
var applyHighlighting = function (highlightableElements, productFilterKeyword) {
for(var i =0; i< highlightableElements.length; i++){
    var regexp = new RegExp(productFilterKeyword, 'ig');
    highlightableElements[i].innerHTML = highlightableElements[i].innerHTML.replace(regexp, '<span style="background-color: yellow">' + productFilterKeyword + '</span>');
}
```

There's no need to work out a replacement keyword if all you're doing is adding html around an existing word.

Comment: @I Stanley - Actually I'm trying to match/filter search string as it is in target String - i.e. I have 4 string as "Diesel Engine" , "Electrical Engine" and if I search for 'e'  - then All 'e' and 'E' should have background color Yellow (highlighted) - but currently something happening like this - "Diesel engine" and "ElEctrical EnginE" 

I can't use productFilterKeyword  as it is because it can be 'e' or 'E' (for example) - so in order to keep the letters as it is - what I should do here?

Comment: You should use `$&` to refer to the regex match, as I said in my answer.

Comment: You're welcome, I wrote you a working example with something important you might've forgotten. And please don't accept wrong answers.